# Parse Object & Array to ListView android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I lost 4 hour to set Object or Array for an Android app showing to listview, unfortunately the result is null.
I wanna get :

- posts--> id, url, title and content, and then
- categories --> id & title, and last
- attachment --> images --> full -- > url

.......

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 4,
    "count_total": 4,
    "pages": 1,
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "url": "url,
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "2014 Yamaha FZ1",
            "title_plain": "2014 Yamaha FZ1",
            "content": "",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "slug": "sport-motorcycle",
                    "title": "Sport Motorcycle",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "post_count": 2
                }
            ],
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "first_name": "",
            },
            "comments": [],
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "url": "image url",
                    "slug": "yamaha-fz1",
                    "title": "2014 Yamaha FZ1 ",
                    "description": "",
                    "caption": "",
                    "parent": 16,
                    "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                    "images": {
                        "full": {
                            "url": "http://demo..jpg",
                            "width": 640,
                            "height": 426
                        },
                        "thumbnail": {
                            "url": "http://demo..jpg",
                            "width": 150,
                            "height": 150
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "url": "http://demo..jpg",
                            "width": 300,
                            "height": 199
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "url": "http://demo..jpg",
                            "width": 640,
                            "height": 426
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "comment_count": 0,
            "comment_status": "open",
            "thumbnail": "http://demo..jpg",
            "custom_fields": {
                "slide": [
                    "http://demo..jpg"
                ]
            },
           ........
}
```

Please help, I'm very confuse :( Thanks in advance

my code :

```
JsonArrayRequest postRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, 
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        PostModel pm = new PostModel();
                        JSONObject posts = obj.getJSONObject("posts");
                        pm.settitle(posts.getString("title"));
                        pm.settitlePlain(posts.getString("titleplain"));
                        JSONObject category = obj.getJSONObject("category");

                        postList.add(pm);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
```

**Solution :**

1. For checking if your Json valid or not just use this [link](http://jsonlint.com/)
2. Check your Object or Array at this [link](http://json.parser.online.fr/), so that you can determine the root.
3. Last on this study, this is valid code :

   ```
                   JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray("posts");
                   for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject obj = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                           PostModel pm = new PostModel();
                           pm.setJudul(obj.getString("title"));
                           pm.setIsi(obj.getString("content"));

                       JSONArray categories = obj.getJSONArray("categories");
                       for (int k = 0; k < categories.length(); k++) {
                           JSONObject obj1 = categories.getJSONObject(k);
                           pm.setCategory(obj1.getString("title"));
                       }

                       JSONObject thumbnail = obj.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                       for (int j = 0; j < thumbnail.length(); j++) {
                           JSONObject medium = thumbnail.getJSONObject("medium");
                           pm.setThumbnail(medium.getString("url"));
                       }

                       postList.add(pm);

                   }
   ```

Comment: Dya, so you have problem in parsing the Json Data right?

Comment: @Dya,your json is invalid.

Comment: First check the variable which you are posting to server contains a right key value?? Second this because of that Json would be invalid. For checking if your Json valid or not just use this link http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @pratt : hi. I'm so glad to meet you again.. I can't get data onRespose.

Comment: @Haresh: Json working well, I just post part of it.

Comment: @piyush : yes' I've tried there but still confused to take the object

Comment: @Dya This line is wrong  `JSONObject posts = obj.getJSONObject("posts");`. Because your first tag is `JSONArray` not a `JSONObject`. So you need to change it.

Comment: @PiyushGupta,As per json response "posts" is JSONArray not JSONObject.

Comment: @HareshChhelana So in my comment what i have suggested her? Please read comment again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `JsonObjectRequest` not `JsonArrayRequest` since you are receiving object not array

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: But first thing its Json is not valid. This should be comment or add some part of code here!!

Comment: I've tried using JsonObjectRequest, working only for first object with string : JSONObject phone = response.getJSONObject("posts"); and next the result is null

Comment: @Dya Can you provide a URL of it??

Comment: @Dya Ok no problem. Just remove your above comment!

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need outer loop as it is one JSONObject and check this

```
JSONObject posts = obj.getJSONObject("posts");
```

to

```html
JSONObject posts = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
for(int i=0;i<posts.length();i++){
   JSONObject checkObj = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                           //and rest parse it as it is
                                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Gson.

Gson is a library from Google which use reflection to parse JSON Strings, and in easy case like yours its magic! So, your only work should be create the model object with the structure of your JSON.

```
public class YourObject {
    private String status;
    private int count;
    private int count_total;
    private int pages;
    private List<Post> posts;
}

public class Post {
    private int id;
    private String url;
    private String title;
    private String title_plain;
    private String content;
    private List<Category> categories;
    //... and so on
}
```

You not need to do anything else. Then, to parse just use one line:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourObject yourObject = gson.fromJson("yourJSONstring", YourObject.class);
```

And thats all. You can find Gson here --> https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: thank you for advice but if I switch to the other code. everything's gonna be complicated, right?... I'll try after solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Here taken ArrayList of HashMap instead custom model class :

```
JSONArray postsJsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> postList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
for(int j=0;j<postsJsonArray.length();j++){
    HashMap<String,Object> post = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    post.put("id",postsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
    post.put("url",postsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("url"));
    post.put("title",postsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));
    post.put("content",postsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("content"));

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONArray categoriesJsonArray = postsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("categories");
    for(int k=0;k<categoriesJsonArray.length();k++) {
        HashMap<String, String> category = new HashMap<String, String>();
        category.put("id", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
        category.put("title", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));
        categoryList.add(category);
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> attachmentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONArray attachmentJsonArray = postsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("categories");
    for(int l=0;l<attachmentJsonArray.length();l++) {
        HashMap<String, String> attachment = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attachment.put("id", attachmentJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("image").getJSONObject("full").getString("url"));
        attachmentList.add(attachment);
    }
    post.put("attachment",attachmentList);
    postList.add(post);
}
```

Comment: I'll Try now, wait.. I will let you know the result. :) Thank you

Comment: Where I have to put the code? If without custom model class? How about adapter set to listview? Sorry if I bother you

Comment: @Dya,you mean dont know how to access data from ArrayList HashMap ?

Comment: I just understand the rule of your code. I don't know where to put it? because custom is required. one of requirement in my study.

Comment: So you need to use Model class. For your every JSONArray you need to make Model class (also call as getter setter method) and for them also every arraylist too.@Dya

Comment: yes of course.. "Model Class & Adapter Class" has been finish .. only objects/arrays that hinder my job

Comment: @Dya So for every JSONArray have you created a Model class?

Comment: @Dya Share me the URL of your JSON data to my Id which is available in my SO profile.

Comment: yes.. I create ArrayList<String> for post etc.. That's right or wrong? oh my god.. I'm very confused.. well.. I would try & understand all of your help. I must to learn more. my post -1, bad reputation :(

Comment: @Dya Yes you are going to in right direction. Don't be confused. You have to just create inner JSONArray and create Model class for particular JSONArray and in last add main Model Class object to your main arraylist.

Comment: @PiyushGupta and ALL : OK. Thank you so much, When The problem solved, I'll get back to post the solution :)

Comment: @Dya Ok great. Best of luck. I hope you can do it. But still u have a issue then share your URL to my id.

Comment: @PiyushGupta : Hi.. yes of course, Thanks.. I'm just explore any sample, everything is right.. then I don't know where I put solution. whether create new post or edit. I do not want the error reoccur, thereby reducing the points. Thank you for your help. I shared code at this link http://www.codeshare.io/VyALl

Answer (score 0):

```
       JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonobj) {


      try {
    for(int i=0;i<jsonobj.getJSONArray("posts").length();i++){

                String id=jsonobj.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

   for(int j=0;j<jsonobj.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").length();j++){
            String title=jsonobj.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").getJSONObject(j).getString("title");
            }
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });
```